# How to get the number in string format for json format?

Tags: php, json, stdclass

I write this code to output as json format for google chart. however, the return value for number become a string and can't be read by google chart.

```
$rows = array();
foreach($data as $item) {
$a = new stdClass;
$a->v = $item->location_name;
$a->f = null;

$b = new stdClass;
$b->v = $item->count;
$b->f = null;

$c = new stdClass;
$c->c = array($a, $b);

$rows[] = $c;

}
$cols1 = new stdClass;
$cols1->id = '';
$cols1->label = 'STATE';
$cols1->pattern = '';
$cols1->type = "string";

$cols2 = new stdClass;
$cols2->id = '';
$cols2->label = 'TOTAL';
$cols2->pattern = '';
$cols2->type = "number";

$returndata = new stdClass;
$returndata->cols = array($cols1, $cols2);
$returndata->rows = $rows;

echo json_encode($returndata);
```

the output become like this:
[image: the number should not be in string format]

the query is like this:

```
$sql = "Select ljl.location_id, count(ljj.job_id) as count, ljl.location_name from {local_jobs_job} ljj inner join {local_jobs_location} ljl on ljj.job_location = ljl.location_id group by ljl.location_name";
```

Comment: If  you were not needing a json encoded string, then why make one?

Comment: i want it to be in json format but the number value in number format not string format, like this ; {"v":2,"f":null}]} not the one with "2"

Comment: the number value with " " cannot be read by google chart

Comment: As you are applying the values, just type cast them, like `$val = (string) 2;`

Comment: You can do by convert known number column to number such as `$b->v = intval($item->count);` or `(int) $item->count`

Comment: thank you brian, your answer is correct but cannot solve directly my problem.

Comment: Thanks to @vietnguyen09. your answer solve my problem perfectly. but i cannot accept your answer as you answer as a comment. u can copy and answer and i will accept the answer..thanks once again. it works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do by cast known "string-number" column to number such as `$b->v = intval($item->count);` or `(int) $item->count`